# Websphere 8 / Spring security (LDAP) / not redirecting to login.xhtml

Tags: spring, jsf, configuration, primefaces, websphere

I try to get LDAP and Spring on a Websphere 8 running. It somehow does, but it does not forward any requests to my login.xhtml.

Means, that it looks like you are logged in, but you cannot click anything on that page and you are not forwarded to the login page.

If I call it directly (/faces/login.xhtml), log in and then click around, everything works as expected, so it is just that my application does not forward me to the required loginpage.

Hope you guys have a good idea.

My web.xml looks like that:

```
<!-- removed non-relevant parts-->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

My applicationSecurity.xml looks like that:

```
<security:http pattern="/faces/ressources/**" security="none"/>
<security:http auto-config="true" pattern="/**">
  <!-- Login pages -->
  <security:form-login login-page="/faces/login.xhtml" default-target-url="/faces/index.xhtml"
                       login-processing-url="/faces/j_spring_security_check"
                       authentication-failure-url="/faces/login.xhtml" />
  <security:logout logout-success-url="/faces/login.xhtml" />
  <!-- Security zones -->
  <!-- secured -->
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/faces/index.xhtml" access="ROLE_APP_QPA_ADMIN,ROLE_APP_QPA_USER" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/faces/datadictionary/**" access="ROLE_APP_QPA_ADMIN,ROLE_APP_QPA_USER" />
  <security:intercept-url pattern="/faces/templates/**" access="ROLE_APP_QPA_ADMIN,ROLE_APP_QPA_USER" />
</security:http>
```

I have no clue what else I could do.
I use Spring as shared Library, if that matters.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but do you have a typo on this line or is that the actual url pattern?  `<security:http pattern="/faces/ressources/**" ..`

Comment: no, thats not a type, i use primefaces in my login.xhtml and this one needs the ressources dir ... or not?